# Prerequisites for Vakil's "Foundations of Algebraic Geometry" (Or other texts)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, book-recommendation

Good day to you all.

I'm currently an undergraduate student with quite a strong affinity for self studying certain topics which interest me. One area which has fascinated me for quite a while is algebraic geometry, especially the (apparently) incredibly abstract machinery used in the modern formulation. 
I've so far been able to ascertain that two good books on the subject are:

*Algebraic Geometry* - R. Hartshorne

*Foundations of Algebraic Geometry* - Ravi Vakil.

Having looked through the ToCs for these books, it appears that Vakil's book is much more comprehensive, but I cannot entirely say for sure. I think I want to set this book as a goal, a mountain to be climbed, so to speak. Of course, before I set such a goal I need to know whether or not it is at all realistic.

The introduction to the text seems to indicate that Aluffi's Algebra text, as well as some general topology and basic notions from 1st or 2nd year undergraduate, will suffice as prerequisites, and I'm wondering if anyone who has read the book could confirm or deny this.

What more would be needed for this book, or for Hartshorne's?

If you would like a rough idea of my current mathematical level, I am currently only in my first year of an undergraduate degree at Oxford, but have so far already worked through *Introduction to Abstract Algebra* by W. Nicholson (which covers the usual stuff up to Galois) as well as a few other topics such as some axiomatic set theory, basic real analysis (up to integration), and of course the linear algebra, geometry, etc. already covered in my course. I'm currently working through *Algebra: Chapter 0* by Aluffi as a second Algebra text, as well as *Introduction to Complex Analysis* by H. Priestley, and *Introduction to Metric and Topological Spaces* by W. Sutherland.

By the time I've finished these books, will I likely have enough of a background to begin to tackle Vakil's book? If not, what more would be required?

I will understand if this is an incredibly naive question, and I apologise if this is so. I'm not entirely clear on the level of mathematical maturity required for the text, hopefully my current reading list will reveal mine. I welcome any suggestions of other places to look to sate my curiosity, though bear in mind one of the main attractions to me at the moment is the abstraction.

As always, my tags are guesswork.

Comment: This is a hard question to answer. You have a lot of time, in some sense, so I wonder whether it makes sense to look at something like Reid or Shafarevich's undergraduate books first. Abstraction is appealing but the real trick is learning some geometry, and I wonder whether Vakil's book takes too long to get there. On the other hand I don't see why you couldn't start reading it now — I don't think it really covers more than Hartshorne but it is more self-contained and friendly.

Comment: To put it a different way I don't think his suggested prerequisites are a lie, assuming Aluffi gives you some practice calculating with tensor products and localization. I doubt you even need to go through all of that book.

Comment: I think Vakil is a good choice. It is much more self contained and leaves out way less detail then hartshorne. Also it is really well written. I would just go for it and if you need some background to understand some particular statement look it up.

Comment: @math635 Thanks :) I'm going to finish the books I'm currently going through first (don't want to leave something half-done) but I'll take a leap of faith afterwards, then!

Comment: @Hoot Thank you, I want to read Aluffi's book for it's own sake as well, but it's encouraging to know that the book is not light years away from me now :) I think I'll give it a go once I've finished my current texts

Comment: @Hoot If it turns out to be too abstract, and without enough geometry for me, then I'll come back down and try your suggestions, instead.

Comment: I agree with the comments that it might be better to start with books at a lower level than Hartshorne. But to answer the question, I would read *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* by Atiyah and Macdonald before starting a "hard" algebraic geometry text. Occasionally, you may need certain results from other books like Matsumura's *Commutative Ring Theory*, but the exposition is better in Atiyah and Macdonald.